# Stop style bundling adding xml closing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, bundling-and-minification

When using mvc style bundles:

```
@Styles.Render("~/content/site")
```

It will always render your style sheets with a self closing tag:

```
<link href="/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Is there any way to stop this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `@Styles.RenderFormat`:

```
@Styles.RenderFormat(@"<link href=""{0}"" rel=""stylesheet""></link>",
                      "~/content/site")
```

Comment: If you do this, does it render all the seperate style sheets in the bundle?

Comment: Apparently, yes. See my edited code. The docs (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.optimization.styles.renderformat(v=vs.110).aspx) ask that the second parameter be a virtual path

Comment: Excellent, exactly what I needed. Thanks!